# Compare types in Python

Tags: python, class, vendor

I'm making an infrastructure for dynamic loading of modules. Each module should contain one class inherited from same base class.

The structure of modules is this:

```
app
\- vendors
 \- __init__.py
 \- vendor_base.py
 \- vendor1.py
 \- vendor2.py
...
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .vendor_base import VendorBase
self = sys.modules[__name__]
__all__ = []
vendors = []
modules = [ f
    for f in glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
    if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')
]
for module in modules:
    with open(module, 'rb') as fp:
        module_name = splitext(basename(module))[0]
        ma = imp.load_module(
            'app.vendors.' + module_name, 
            fp, basename(module), ('.py', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE)) 
        classes = { c for c in ma.__dict__.items() 
            if isinstance(c[1], type) and issubclass(c[1], VendorBase) }
        for class_pair in classes:
            setattr(self, class_pair[0], class_pair[1])
            if class_pair[0] not in __all__:
                __all__.append(class_pair[0])
                if issubclass(class_pair[1], VendorBase):
                    vendors.append(class_pair[1])
```

`vendor_base.py`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class VendorBase(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return subclass is not cls and cls in subclass.__mro__

    @abstractmethod
    def post_purchase_order(self, purchase_order):
        pass
```

`vendor1.py`:

```
from . import VendorBase

class Vendor1(VendorBase):
    def post_purchase_order(self, purchase_order):
        pass
```

`vendor2.py`:

```
from . import VendorBase

class Vendor2(VendorBase):
    def post_purchase_order(self, purchase_order):
        pass
```

So I expect classes Vendor1 and Vendor2 to be loaded and be available in module app.vendors (in `__all__` and `vendors`). However they aren't loaded. I've checked that comparison of classes in `VendorBase.__subclasshook__()` doesn't work as expected.

When I run `issubclass(VendorBase, Vendor1)` I get `False`. Moreover even when in debugger `VendorBase.__subclasshook__(cls, subclass)` where:

> cls

> 'app.vendors.vendor_base.VendorBase'>

> subclass

> 'app.vendors.vendor_base.VendorBase'>

I check `cls is subclass` I still get `False`.
I though it could be related to different imported base class names in vendor classes modules. So I ensured that `VendorBase` is imported from `vendors` where it's also used. But still there seem to be different instances of classes.

Comment: You are looking for `isinstance()`. `is` in Python is an identity check; `1 is int` returns `False`

Comment: You might want to just use entrypoints instead of rolling your own loader... https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-package-metadata

Comment: Re `issubclass(VendorBase, Vendor1)`.  You've got the arguments backwards.

Comment: @Flair I believe `isinstance()` applies to objects. I'm comparing classes (not objects)

Comment: @AKX Wouldn't it require re-running setup every time you add a plugin? The idea is that new module is loaded as soon as file is put to the target directory

Answer (score 0):

You are already using module imp to load then use it as well to find.

> imp.find_module(name[, path])

Please post how it goes

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how finding module is related

Comment: First and foremost is it is pythonic way. Why code yourself when you have a tested code available.

Comment: I still don't understand how it's related to the problem.